# Getting a String resource from the secondary language file when this language is not selected

Tags: android, kotlin, resources

I have two languages in my application, English and Arabic. and in the string resource files I have an array called "employment_array". I want to be able to grab this array from the language that is not selected. for example: if the user is using English language I want to grab the array from the Arabic String file.

I'm using the code below, but it is grabbing the array from the file of the selected language.

```
val employmentPositions: Array<String> = resources.getStringArray(R.array.employment_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to get a specific resources for a specific locale

```
fun getLocalizedResources() : Resources{
    var conf = resources.configuration
    conf = Configuration(conf)
    conf.setLocale(Locale("ar"))
    val localizedContest = fActivity.createConfigurationContext(conf)
    return localizedContest.resources
}
```

after that you can use the function to get whatever resources you desire like

```
val employmentPositions: Array<String> = getLocalizedResources().getStringArray(R.array.employment_array)
```